# Wamp server doesnt support PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, wamp

I need your help, I have following problem. I have installed WAMP server(PHP 5.3.13, mysql5.5.24, apache 2.2.22) on my PC and it is giving me this Error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in ...

I was trying to join PHP and PostgreSQL (i have installed PostGreSQL 9.3).

I already tried
[plaatsoft.nl](http://www.plaatsoft.nl/wamp-postgresql-integration)   but it doesn´t work for me - when i test it, it writes on screen "no" - i don´t know why.

Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: And if you need Postgresql only, maybe you can see this pkg: https://bitnami.com/stack/wapp

Comment: I added this LoadFile “C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/libpq.dll” to httpd.conf and restart WAMP (extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll and
extension=php_pgsql.dll was uncommented in php.ini)

Comment: I will need mysql too.

Comment: and is there a `libpq.dll` in that directory?

Comment: in what directory ? it is in php.5.3.13

Comment: `"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/libpq.dll"`

Comment: Kindof-related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24529352/398670

Comment: How can this help me? Im working on Windows.

Comment: Ok, i got it .. The proble was, that i didnt check php.ini in apache conf.. Thanks guys.